# Redirect user after jquery POST

Tags: php, jquery, post, window.location

I have a page with a list and a div to be clicked:

```
    <ul id='chosen'>        
            <li id="1">Item 1</li>
            <li id="2">Item 2</li>          
    </ul>

    <div class="play"></div>
```

Then I have some jquery whose puppose it is on the div click to grab the list item id's and send them via POST to a php page, which updates a session variable with the list item id's.

jquery:

```
$(document).on('click','.play',function(){
    var chosen = $('#chosen').sortable('toArray');
        $.post('../ext/php/chosen.php', {value: chosen}, function() {
            window.location = "http://www.xyz123.com/play_d.php"
            });
});
```

chosen.php:

```
<?php
session_start();    
if (isset($_POST['value']))
{
    $_SESSION[section_remember] = $_POST['value'];
}
?>
```

After the Session variable is set and returned I'd like the jquery to redirect the user to a separate page (play_d.php) which then reads the session variable and does some stuff with it.

The jquery code  and session variable stuff works if I comment out the `window.location` part and then manually go to the page rather then redirect, but when I ask the jquery to redirect the user it seems like it interrupts the setting of the session variable and it all breaks down.

I'm guessing I'm missing something fundamental here, but I've researched and can't find the solution. Am I asking the browser to go to two different pages almost simultaneously? If so, how do I make sure the session variable is set, and only afterwards redirect the user?

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: use ajax success function for redirect..

Comment: If `play_d.php` is on the same server / uses the same session, why are you using ajax? Just post normally to `chosen.php` and use a `header` redirect in php to go directly to the final destination.

Comment: They are both on the same server. I've tried adding `header('Location: http://www.xyz123.com/play_d.php');` to chosen.php but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'd have to get rid of the ajax all together and replace it with a script that adds the value you want to send to a hidden form field.

Comment: you are using a callback function which might gets invoked while the chosen.php file is still running, that might mess-up your php script there. you should use the on-success event of the ajax call and there you should redirect to wherever.. [jquey ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Try this..

window.location.replace("http://www.xyz123.com/play_d.php");

and you can use this also 

window.location.href = "http://www.xyz123.com/play_d.php";